# Change element when in top half of the viewport with jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll, viewport

I'm trying to rotate an element when it enters the top half of the viewport.  I have several of these elements on the page and if one enters the top of the viewport it should rotate 180 degrees.

The rotation bit I can do but how do i detect if one enters the top half of the viewport when the user is scrolling?

**EDIT:**

I got this far but $(this) doesn't contain the tested .section-anchor.  Can anyone expand on this?

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($('.section-anchor').offset().top > $(window).height() / 2) {
        $(this).css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(180deg)'});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

That is an old question, but best way is something like:

```
if ($('.section-anchor').offset().top < ($(window).scrollTop() + ($(window).height() / 2))) {}
```